# Run iOS Codesign from php page

Tags: php, ios, apache, keychain, codesign

I try to setup a local website to resign ipa file. but I have an issue with codesign command.
the command works properly when I run it from the shell terminal.
But it shows this error when it run from php: "no identity found".

I run an Apache server with php.

I think the account used to run apache server haven't access to keychain library.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly found a solution,

my command was :
codesign -f --verbose -s D7F14A3C73E20026ECB384BB7F7FCAEB76EF24B3 --resource-rules Payload/my.app/ResourceRules.plist Payload/my.app

I went to Keychain Acces, and copy my certificate from Session to System.

and it works